# How to merge two or more Safari Bookmarks.plist files together?

Tags: macos, mac, safari, plist, bookmarks

I do not use iCloud to sync my Mac and I have several Safari Bookmarks.plist files that were manually backed up at different times. Thus each contain some of the same items while some contain items the others do not.

How can the contents of these Bookmarks.plist files be merged together?

Comment: Reading the [edited original question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/299308/2) I would conclude that the latest bookmark.plist contains all bookmarks and merging isn't necessary (bookmarks-2 > bookmarks-1 (=imported bookmarks-2 + additions) >  bookmarks (=imported bookmarks-1 + additions)).

Comment: @klanomath no the latest bookmarks.plist file do not contain the old bookmarks cause it's size is smaller than the previous files!

Comment: Note that I edited the original question for two reasons: 1. It was a run on paragraph, making it difficult to read. 2. It contained total unnecessary background information. Which regardless of the actual content of each Bookmarks.plist file, it had no bearing on how to merge multiple Bookmarks.plist files. (Presumably so there would not be any duplicates.) - My subsequent answer should explain the rational behind my edit.

Comment: @user3439894 It's ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither macOS or Safari provide a direct way to merge multiple Bookmarks.plist files so as not to contain duplicate items.

Some choices are:

- Manually import each Bookmarks.plist file (Safari > File > Import Bookmarks...) and then manually arrange and reorganize while manually deleting duplicates.
- Use a third-party utility to manage the Bookmarks.plist files so as to utilize any tools the third-party utility provides to remove duplicate items.

  - BookmarkApp: sort & delete duplicate bookmarks

    - [Developer Website](https://appssalon.de/en/bookmarkapp/)
    - [Mac App Store Preview](https://itunes.apple.com/app/bookmarks-duplicates-cleaner/id984977589?mt=12&ls=1)
  - **URL Manager Pro** : *the* bookmark manager

    - [Developer Website](http://www.url-manager.com)
    - [Mac App Store Preview](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/url-manager-pro/id449825241?mt=12)
  - [Safari Extensions - Search for: bookmarks](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/?q=bookmark) - At the time of this search it contained "69 results found for 'bookmark'", and some *may* have the capacity to remove duplicates.
  - Google, or other Search Engine, for other third-party utilities to manage Bookmarks.
- Write your own utility to manage Safari Bookmarks to remove all duplicates from a set of combined Bookmarks.plist files.

Note: I am not affiliated with, nor have used the utilities mentioned herein.